# viewDidAppear is called when app is started due to significant location change, even when it is not visible and in background

Tags: ios, iphone, location, core-location

I've noticed that `viewDidAppear` is called when my app is launched (in background) due to a significant location change, even though the screen is off and app is definitely not visible (I was on home screen and screen is off anyway).

In other words, the view did not really appear. I can understand that `viewDidLoad` would be called because this view controller will get instantiated in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, which is what is being called in this case.

But why is `viewDidAppear` getting called if it is not visible on screen (display is off, and I was on home screen anyway)?

Does iOS always call `viewDidAppear` after viewDidLoad, regardless of whether or not it really appears?

If so, how can I distinguish between the view actually appearing and the case described when it is not really visible?

Comment: I have the same problem, though I'm using visit monitoring rather than significant location changes. If the app is not running and it's launched by a visit, viewDidAppear is called in my initial view controller.

Answer (score 3):

You can use your `UIApplication`'s `applicationState` property to distinguish between when `viewDidAppear` is being called by a background launch and when the view actually appears on a user's screen. For example:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)

    let application: UIApplication = UIApplication.sharedApplication()

    switch application.applicationState {
    case .Active:
        // Do something when the view actually appears.
    case .Inactive:
        // The app is briefly Inactive when an it's launched from 
        // "not running/terminated". viewDidAppear might be called while the
        // applicationState property is still set to this.
    case .Background:
        // Don't do anything because the view didn't really appear on screen
        // for the user.
    }
}
```

That seems to do the trick for me when my app is launched in the background by `locationManagerDelegate.locationManager(didVisit)`. I'm fairly confident it will be the same for significant location changes.